# How to connect multi-strand sheathed wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring, stove

We are trying to move our electric stove to another room. However, that room does not have a power outlet that matches the stove. Therefore we want to extend the current stove cable. We want to cut the current cable in halves, and connect a new section of cable in between.

This is the cable that we want to install (AWG 8, 7 strands), what would be a good way to connect two cables of this type together?
[image]

Comment: Does  your stove require a neutral wire?  That cable has no neutral.

Comment: If you MUST extend the cable you’d be better off with ONE splice.  Why must you cut it and add more in the middle, that makes no sense and it introduces a second splice.  Your splice must be in an approved junction box, with cover that remains accessible.  Your better off to do it right the first time and replace the wire with one that’s the correct length.

Comment: Splices need to be in boxes but now that you want to move the outlet 4 wire will be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bad plan.

"We want to cut the current cable in halves, and connect a new section of cable in between."

And then what? Hide the splices in a wall or under cabinets? No. Leave it on the floor or stapled to the wall? No. Run a completely new wire into the stove and get a replacement plug? Yes.

Or do it the right way and install an outlet where the stove now goes.

Answer (score 0):

Mains electrical connections have to happen inside an approved enclosure. And appliance cords cannot run from one room to another without being fixed in place and protected behind conduit. These rules exist to avoid small problems like tripping hazards and bigger problems like electrocution and electrical fires.

**The best solution is to install a new outlet in the room where the stove will go.** This outlet can be wired as an extension off the existing outlet or as a home run back to the service panel.

If this is a rental unit and you can't modify the wiring in the wall then it's possible to make a custom extension cord that terminates with a rated plug on one end and a receptacle in a junction box on the other end. The cord would still be a tripping hazard unless it is secured onto the wall or floor out of the way. And even then it would be advisable (required?) to cover it in surface conduit so that someone doesn't nick it with something and get electrocuted.

Either way you'll have to connect a pair of thick AWG 8 wires inside a junction box. Which gets us back to your initial question. When you want to connect thick wires a conventional wire nut doesn't do a very good job. Instead use insulated splicing blocks. These are much better at making solid connections with thick wires. You can find them [online](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005FMQ5BQ) and at electrical supply houses. I don't recommend using an uninsulated split bolt (except for the bare/green ground wires) because wrapping one of these properly with insulating tape is a lost art.

Comment: Conduit is not required by the NEC. Wire nuts do work well for #8 you just have to get the right size. When moving the outlet to a new room current code would require a 4 wire cable. I down voted because I don't believe this is a good answer at all!